# SIFT matches and recognition?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, object-detection

I am developing an application where I am using SIFT + RANSAC and Homography to find an object (OpenCV C++,Java). The problem I am facing is that where there are many outliers RANSAC performs poorly.

For this reasons I would like to try what the author of SIFT said to be pretty good: voting.

I have read that we should vote in a 4 dimension feature space, where the 4 dimensions are:

- Location [x, y] (someone says Traslation)
- Scale
- Orientation

While with opencv is easy to get the match `scale` and `orientation` with:

```
cv::Keypoints.octave
cv::Keypoints.angle
```

I am having hard time to understand how I can calculate the location.

I have found an [interesting slide](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cv-fall2012/slides/fall2012_02_specific_objects.pdf) where with only `one match` we are able to draw a bounding box:

[image]

But I don't get how I could draw that bounding box with just one match. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the largest set of matched features that fit a geometric transformation from image 1 to image 2.  In this case, it is the similarity transformation, which has 4 parameters: translation `(dx, dy)`, scale change `ds`, and rotation `d_theta`.

Let's say you have matched to features: f1 from image 1 and f2 from image 2. Let `(x1,y1)` be the location of f1 in image 1, let `s1` be its scale, and let `theta1` be it's orientation.  Similarly you have `(x2,y2)`, `s2`, and `theta2` for f2.

The translation between two features is `(dx,dy) = (x2-x1, y2-y1)`.

The scale change between two features is `ds = s2 / s1`.

The rotation between two features is `d_theta = theta2 - theta1`.

So, `dx`, `dy`, `ds`, and `d_theta` are the dimensions of your Hough space. Each bin corresponds to a similarity transformation.

Once you have performed Hough voting, and found the maximum bin, that bin gives you a transformation from image 1 to image 2.  One thing you can do is take the bounding box of image 1 and transform it using that transformation: apply the corresponding translation, rotation and scaling to the corners of the image. Typically, you pack the parameters into a transformation matrix, and use homogeneous coordinates.  This will give you the bounding box in image 2 corresponding to the object you've detected.

Comment: With one match, you don't need the Hough transform. You take the difference in x and y (translation), the difference in the orientation (rotation), and the ratio of scales (scale).  Then you put those into a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

To complete [Dima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13313/dima)'s , one needs to add that the 4D Hough space is quantized into a (possibly small) number of 4D boxes, where each box corresponds to the simiéarity given by its center.

Then, for each possible similarity obtained via a tentative matching of features, add 1 into the corresponding box (or *cell*) in the 4D space. The output similarity is given by the cell with the more votes.

In order to computethe transform from 1 match, just use Dima's formulas in his answer. For several pairs of matches, you may need to use some least squares fit.

Finally, the transform can be applied with the function `cv::warpPerspective()`, where the third line of the perspective matrix is set to `[0,0,1]`.

Comment: this doesn explain how to draw a bounding box with only one single match

Comment: The bounding box is drawn by applying the final similarity (obtained from 1 match or from Hough voting) to the blue and yellow boxes on the Model image, then drawing it in the novel image.

Comment: Can you post an example on how to calulcate the final similarity matrix (just considering one match)?

Answer (score 2):

When using the Hough transform, you create a signature storing the displacement vectors of every feature from the template centroid (either `(w/2,h/2)` or with the help of central moments).

E.g. for 10 SIFT features found on the template, their relative positions according to template's centroid is a `vector<{a,b}>`. Now, let's search for this object in a query image: every SIFT feature found in the query image, matched with one of template's 10, casts a vote to its corresponding centroid.

`votemap(feature.x - a*, feature.y - b*)+=1` where a,b corresponds to this particular feature vector.

If some of those features cast successfully at the same point (clustering is essential), you have found an object instance.

[image]

Signature and voting are reverse procedures. Let's assume `V=(-20,-10)`. So during searching in the novel image, when the two matches are found, we detect their orientation and size and cast a respective vote. E.g. for the right box centroid will be `V'=(+20*0.5*cos(-10),+10*0.5*sin(-10))` away from the SIFT feature because it is in half size and rotated by -10 degrees.

Comment: What do you mean "one match"? What is the nature of the matched feature? A point (x,y) or an area (x,y,a,b,theta) like the yellow box in your examples?

Comment: Then, you'll have to include the SIFT **Descriptor** in the signature and extract from the DescriptorMatcher the rotation and scaling for the matched patches.